# Can a 32-bit processor load a 64-bit memory address using multiple blocks or registers?

Tags: 32-bit, memory-address, cpu-registers, microprocessors

I was doing a little on 32-bit microprocessors and have I have learnt that:

1) A 32-bit microprocessor can only address 2^32 bits of memory which means that the memory pointer size should not exceed 32-bit range i.e. the pointer size should be equal to or less than 32-bit.

2) I also came to know that CPU allocate multiple blocks of memory for things like storing numbers and text, that is up to the program and not related to the size of each address (Source:[here](https://superuser.com/a/698434)).
So is it possible that a CPU can use multiple blocks (registers) to store pointers more than 32-bit in size?

Answer (score 2):

Processors can access an essentially unlimited amount of memory by using variations on a technique called bank switching.  In a simple bank-switching scheme, the memory chips that are wired to a portion of the address space will have some address inputs fed by the processor and some from an external latching device.  Historically, the IBM PC had a 1MB address space, but an expanded memory board would IIRC allow two 16KB regions of that space to be mapped to any of dozens or hundreds of 16KB blocks of memory contained thereon.  Nowadays processors generally have a memory-management unit built-in, which maps 4KB or 64KB blocks of memory to any address within a much larger space, and additional circuitry may, with OS support, expand things further.

The big difficulty with bank switching is that any given address might identify many different places in memory depending upon how the bank-switching hardware is configured, so accessing data from memories in a banked region will generally be more complicated than accessing data in directly-accessible memory and will only be possible from code which knows how the bank-switching hardware works.  Nowadays it's more common to simply use a processor which can access all the memory one needs, but historically bank-switching was often a useful technique for going beyond processor limitations.

Answer (score 1):

You could store a 64 bit pointer using 2 separate locations in memeory. But it probably wouldn't be useful since your processor can only use 32 bit pointers.

Comment: Why is it that a processor can only use 32 bit pointers when it can store pointers more than 32-bits?